# How can import more files simultaneously and clean them in Mathematica?

Tags: string-manipulation, machine-learning

I would like to import three files in Mathematica (I am using the Import function[]) and try to clean them. 
I used

```
Import[#,"Table"]&/@FileNames["/DirectoryPath/*.txt"]
```

to import the files (it is a list, where each file is a string of this list). 
What I would like to know is how to clean each file; for example, if I want to use

```
StringReplace[StringDelete[data, "@"],"\n"..->"\n"]
```

to clean all of them, how could I do? At the end, I would like to train a neural network.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: If you store all the files with your import command: `data=Import[#...]&/@FileNames[...]`, then you can do work on each file with `cleanedata=StringReplace[StringDelete[#, "@"],"\n"..->"\n"]&/@data`

Comment: Thank you MelaGo. The problem is that I need to use all that data as input in a neural network, so probably I need to run them in parallel (are at least 100 files). I also got the following error: String or list of strings expected at position 1 in StringDelete I was thinking of MapThread but I have never used it.

Comment: When you import with `"Table"` it turns your files into lists. If you want to use string functions like `StringReplace` with newlines and such, I think you'll have to keep your files in string or text format. Can you post an example file?

Comment: An example of files that I am importing is:  history1.txt, history2.txt,..., history100.txt Each file contains many lines of text, for example : "The 4th of July in the United States....".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For illustration, here are three text files (copied from the first three paragraphs of this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_Day_(United_States))), called "history1.txt", "history2.txt", and "history3.txt".

```
data = Import[#] & /@ FileNames["history*.txt"]
(*
{"Independence Day (colloquial: the Fourth of July) is a federal \
holiday in the United States commemorating the Declaration of \
Independence of the United States, on July 4, 1776. ...", \
"Independence Day is commonly associated with fireworks, parades, \
barbecues, carnivals, fairs, picnics, concerts, baseball games, \
family reunions, political speeches, and ceremonies, ...", 
"During the American Revolution, the legal separation of the Thirteen \
Colonies from Great Britain in 1776 actually occurred on July 2, when \
the Second Continental Congress voted to approve a resolution of \
independence ..."}
*)
```

You can then do some work on all of the files. For example:

```
StringReplace[#, "Independence Day" -> "July 4th"] & /@ data

(*
{"July 4th (colloquial: the Fourth of July) is a federal holiday in \
the United States commemorating the Declaration of Independence of \
the United States, on July 4, 1776. ...", 
"July 4th is commonly \
associated with fireworks, parades, barbecues, carnivals, fairs, \
picnics, concerts, baseball games, family reunions, political \
speeches, and ceremonies, ...", 
"During the American Revolution, the \
legal separation of the Thirteen Colonies from Great Britain in 1776 \
actually occurred on July 2, when the Second Continental Congress \
voted to approve a resolution of independence ..."}
*)
```